# Flutter: intl, time

Tags: date, flutter, dart, time, flutter-intl

I'm trying to convert the date time using the *intl package*, but the hour that it gives me back is always 8, while here is 10 (I live in Germany). Here's the code:

```
  String test(){
    var now = new DateTime.now();
    var formatter = new DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd_hh');
    String formatted = formatter.format(now);
    return formatted; // something like 2013-04-20
  }
```

and I've also tried something like:

```
var de = new Intl('de_DE');
var format = de.date().add_d().add_H();
```

but the hour is always 8

Comment: Do you get the correct value in the console if you use `print(now)`?

Comment: No, always two hours before (now it's eleven and it gives me 9)

Comment: I print now the timezonename and it gives me GMT. I think that by default is utc. But how can I change this?

Comment: In my case (Spain) it is correctly printed and I have GMT +02:00 Central European Summer Time in my System settings in the phone.

Comment: I had automatic and it gave me GMT + 0. Now I set to germany, giving me GMT + 2,  and the print it's correct. So, it depends by the phone's settings?

Comment: Yes, it takes the values from the phone where you are executing the app.

Comment: I add it as an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

¿Have you tried to change the time zone in the System settings of the phone or emulator where you are executing the app?

The time is taken from the phone itself.